# Firebase get collection document data without running a forEach loop on querySnapshot

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In firebase, when you get more than one document you need to loop through querySnaphot and run doc.data() to get each document data.

Is there a way to get all the documents data without looping every document result in the query, this looks quite expensive as an operation just to get what you would expect from a database query result.

Answer (score 1):

The loop is not expensive.  When you perform the query, the entire set of results is in memory in a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) object.  You can use [forEach()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#foreach) to iterate them, or you can simply iterate the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs)  array property.  Either way is essentially the same speed.  I suggest not being concerned about the loop at all - just make sure you request only the documents you need.

Comment: Thank you Doug for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean.  All of this code to run one query:

```js
import {  initializeApp, getFirestore, getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, collection, getDocs, DocumentData, QueryDocumentSnapshot, query, Query, where } from 'firebase/firestore';

// init
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(config.firebase.prod.app);
const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const firestoreAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
signInWithEmailAndPassword(firestoreAuth, config.firebase.prod.user.email, config.firebase.prod.user.password);
const stripeAccountColl = collection(firestore, "StripeAccount");

// Function
private async getStripeAccount(): Promise<FirebaseStripeAccountIntf> {
    try {
        const q1: Query<DocumentData> = query(this.stripeAccountColl, where("JobNumber", "==", "ABC123"));

        const querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot<DocumentData> = await getDocs(q1);

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (querySnapshot.size) {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>) => {
                    const data: any = doc.data();
                    if (this.debug) {
                        console.debug(`getStripeAccount >> data = ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
                    }
                    resolve(data);
                });
            } else {
                console.error(`getStripeAccount >> query returned no results`);
                reject("query returned no results");
            }
        });
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error(`getStripeAccount >> error = ${error}`);
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}
```